# "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified"

Tags: sql, database, coldfusion, sql-order-by, distinct

I'm building a Query for a db oriented webapp, and running into an issue with SELECT DISTINCT and ORDER BY. I want the first item shown to be determined by a variable (showing which option a user previously selected), then the rest to be sorted normally. My ORDER BY worked fine before I added the DISTINCT option to the select (needed to eliminate duplicates). The columns being sorted appear in my SELECT, so I'm not sure why it won't accept it.

```
WITH COURSE2 AS
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTRING(section_table.crs_cde, 1, 10)) AS CRSID, yr_cde, trm_Cde FROM section_table
    )
    SELECT DISTINCT crs_cde, crs_title
        FROM course_table
        LEFT JOIN COURSE2
        ON crs_cde = CRSID
        WHERE yr_cde = #currentyear#
        AND trm_cde = #currentterm#
        ORDER BY <cfif isDefined("FORM.ndd")>(case crs_cde when '#FORM.ndd#' then 0 else 1 end),</cfif> crs_cde ASC
```

Appreciate any and all help :)

Answer (score 4):

> The columns being sorted appear in my SELECT

Not quite. Just using one of the same columns in a `CASE` statement does not count. The ORDER BY reference has to match the SELECT list - exactly. One alternative is move the CASE into the SELECT list, as a new column. Then sort by the column *alias*:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT crs_cde
           , crs_title
           , CASE crs_cde WHEN 'some value' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS SortOrder

  FROM ...
  ORDER BY SortOrder, crs_cde
```

Couple of other comments about the query:

> `WHERE yr_cde = #currentyear#`
>   `AND trm_cde = #currentterm#`

1. That will cause the query to be converted into an *INNER JOIN*. If you really need an outer join, move those filters into the CTE statement.
2. Be sure to wrap ALL variable parameters in `cfqueryparam`. Using raw variables in queries puts the database at risk for sql injection.
3. For clarity and readability, consider adding table aliases and using them to prefix all of the columns in the join query.
4. Scope all variables, ie use `FORM.someField` instead of just `someField`

Putting it all together, something like this (not tested)

```
WITH COURSE2 AS
(
   SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTRING(crs_cde, 1, 10)) AS CRSID
   FROM   section_table
   WHERE  yr_cde = <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.currentYear#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
   AND    trm_cde = <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.currentTerm#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
)
SELECT DISTINCT ct.crs_cde
         , ct.crs_title
         <cfif structKeyExists(FORM, "ndd")>
         ,  CASE ct.crs_cde 
                 WHEN <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.ndd#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"> THEN 0 
                 ELSE 1 
            END AS SortOrder
         </cfif> 
FROM  course_table ct LEFT JOIN COURSE2 c2 ON c2.CRSID = ct.crs_cde
ORDER BY 
     <cfif structKeyExists(FORM, "ndd")>SortOrder,</cfif> 
     crs_cde ASC
```